# Creating pods across data centres

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

a newbie question related to Kubernetes / OpenShift. The physical infrastructure for our OpenShift cluster is spread across two data centres.

When I create pods, how can I guarantee / choose a particular node / data centre where it would be located?

Comment: Please look on the official documentation regarding [Placing pods on specific nodes using node selectors](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/nodes/pods/nodes-pods-node-selectors.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add labels(arbitary key value pairs) on the nodes of your kubernetes cluster.

```
kubectl label nodes node1 datacenter=xyz
```

then you can either use nodeselector or nodeaffnity in the pod spec to schedule a pod to a node with a specific label.

As an example of using nodeselector

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    env: test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  nodeSelector:
    datacenter: xyz
```

Official docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) with more details and examples.